# My counter isn't running properly

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, counter, boolean-logic

I'm working on a simple project for my class to check if a password contains only numbers and letters and no other characters, but I keep getting an error in my variable count.

The code runs through the correct `if` statement, but it doesn't add to the counter. In the end, it also returns `True` instead of `False`. Any help?

```
def chaCheck2(password):
    for i in range(len(password)):
        goodCha = 0
        badCha = 0
        if 48 <= ord(password[i]) <= 57 or 65 <= ord(password[i]) <= 90 or 
        97 <= 
        ord(password[i]) <= 122:
            goodCha += 1
            print ("goodCha: ", goodCha)
        else:
            badCha += 1
            print("badCha: ", badCha)
    if badCha > 0:
        print("False")
    else: print("True")

chaCheck2("a.bcd")
```

Output:

```
goodCha:  1
badCha:  1
goodCha:  1
goodCha:  1
goodCha:  1
True
```

Comment: This was the input I used. (chaCheck2("a.bcd"))

Comment: How about using `str.isalnum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: This answer is to only show the problems in your code. It is not at all a good/fast/pythonic solution. There are many other better ways to do this.</sup>

You are creating the variables `goodCha` and `badCha` inside the `for` loop, and so, on each iteration, they get set to `0`. So, first, initialize them before the `for` loop.

Secondly, you can use `for i in password:` to get the characters, instead of using `for i in range(len(password))`.

```
def chaCheck2(password):
    goodCha = 0
    badCha = 0
    for c in password:
        if 48 <= ord(c) <= 57 or 65 <= ord(c) <= 90 or 97 <= ord(c) <= 122:
            goodCha += 1
            print("goodCha: ", goodCha)
        else:
            badCha += 1
            print("badCha: ", badCha)
    if badCha > 0:
        print("False")
    else:
        print("True")

chaCheck2("a.bcd")
```

Output:

```
goodCha:  1
badCha:  1
goodCha:  2
goodCha:  3
goodCha:  4
False
```

Comment: ok that helps a ton. I know there are lots of better way to accomplish this, but I'm just a beginner in a 1400 CS class. Thanks!